# Key mapping an association applied to a distribution

Tags: programming, distributions, associations

I am attempting to import data from a database, group it according to a given identification parameter, get it's statistically relevant information, and then export it as a JSON object for visualization in d3. Previously, I had been hard-coding functions for each piece of my data to be passed through a `FormatForJSON` function:

```
FormatForJSON[function_, domain_] := 
<|"function" -> ToString@function, 
"output" -> Map[<|"x" -> #, 
"y" -> function@#|> &, domain]|>
```

Instead, I would like to automate this by building the JSON during the post-processing of the import thru the use of this function:

```
JSONBuilder[ID_String, data_List] := 
Block[{records, H, fittedDist, pdf, pdfFunc},
(*container for records*)
records = <||>;

(*stats*)
H = FindDistribution[data];
pdfFunc = PDF[H];

(*fitted dist info*) 
fittedDist = <|"dist" -> ToString@H, 
"params" -> KeyMap[ToString]@(Association@(H)), 
"pdf" -> ToString@FullForm@PDF[H][x], 
"pdfFunction" -> <|"function" -> ToString@FullForm[pdfFunc@x], 
"line" -> FormatForJSON[pdfFunc, data]|>|>;

(*add all info to records*)
AppendTo[records, ID -> fittedDist]]
```

However, I am getting an association error in `KeyMap`:

```
KeyMap::invak: "The argument Association[H] is not a valid Association"
```

I previously ran `JSONBuilder` using `DistributionFitTest` and it worked just fine; all I have modified is that function to `FindDistribution` with the appropriate arguments, so I don't understand why the association wouldn't occur like normal (no pun intended). They have the same `Attributes`, and I've limited it to find the single best distribution (as opposed to producing several in a list, which I think would require an `AssociationThread`); is there a subtle difference between the two functions that I am just not seeing?

**Edit: Here is the working code for when `DistributionFitTest` is used:**

```
JSONBuilder[ID_String, data_List] := 
Block[{records, H, fittedDist, pdf, pdfFunc},
(*container for records*)
records = <||>;

(*stats*)
H = DistributionFitTest[data, Automatic, "HypothesisTestData"];
pdfFunc = PDF[H["FittedDistribution"]];

(*fitted dist info*)
fittedDist = <|
"dist" -> ToString@H["FittedDistribution"], 
"params" -> KeyMap[ToString]@Association@(H["FittedDistributionParameters"]), 
"pdf" -> ToString@FullForm@PDF[H["FittedDistribution"]][x],
"pdfFunction" -> <|"function" -> ToString@FullForm[pdfFunc@x], 
"line" -> FormatForJSON[pdfFunc, data]|>|>;

(*add all info to records*)
AppendTo[records, ID -> fittedDist]]
```

**Update:**

Apparently the object that `DistributionFitTest[data, Automatic, "HypothesisTestData"]` outputs is listable. I have reason to believe that my data doesn't follow a normal distribution; is there a way to have `FindDistribution` output a `List`?

Comment: That error is caused because `H` is not a list, meaning you cannot make it into an `Association`.

Comment: @JHM that makes sense, but then what doesn't make sense to me is why it worked for `DistributionFitTest`, which doesn't produce a list either.

Comment: That is odd... `DistributionFitTest` returns a `Real`, so it can't be made an `Association`. Could you post the working code that has `DistributionFitTest`?

Comment: @JHM Certainly. Went ahead and edited the post to add it in

Comment: `DistributionFitTest[data, Automatic, 
  "HypothesisTestData"]["FittedDistributionParameters"]` does give you a `List` of `Rules` so it works...

Comment: @JHM I didn't know that the object it outputs is listable. I guess the real question is how can I make `FindDistribution` output a `List`. I'll go ahead and update my op

Comment: Try `"params" -> Association[Rule @@@ Cases[Flatten[{{"x", "y", "z"}, List @@ H}, {2}], {_, _}]]` in your `fittedDist`. I believe `FindDistribution` doesn't produce a `List` of `Rule`s as an output.

Comment: @JHM I'm getting reccurent `FindDistribution::conenf: The data will be treated as continuous. Use the option TargetFunctions->Discrete otherwise` messages; the evaluation is pretty computationally intensive and it can't finish.

Comment: That error is from the evaluation of `H = FindDistribution[data]`. I believe it's okay to ignore that message; it is just telling you that your machine is going to assume your data is continuous. Or, you simply say `H = FindDistribution[data, TargetFunctions -> "Continuous"]` (unless you want the discrete distribution fits).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42900/discussion-between-lame-ov2-0-and-jhm).